# A human traveling back in time to when both Homo sapiens and Neanderthals were around

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read a novel once in which a human scientist travel back in time, brings a Homo sapiens or Neanderthal child back and they do experiment on the child. At some point the scientist finds it morally wrong and take the kid back to its own time.

After going back in time she stops the fighting between Homo sapiens and Neanderthal.

This is the extent I remember from the novel and I will be grateful if someone remember the novel and can tell me the name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could it be **The Ugly Little Boy**, by Isaac Asimov?

The [Wikipedia summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ugly_Little_Boy) for the original novella sounds like that might be it:

> A Neanderthal child is brought to the present day as a result of time travel experiments by a research organization, Stasis Inc. He cannot be removed from his immediate area because of the vast energy loss and time paradoxes that would result. To take care of him, Edith Fellowes, a children's nurse, is engaged.

(There's more on Wikipedia)

There was also a novel written by Robert Silverberg, that was based on and extended the original story. It had the same name, although it was published as **Child of Time** in the UK.

Comment: +1. I haven't read the novel, only the short story, but from the OP's description, it must be the former. The short story ends when she goes back in time; there's nothing about fighting in there.