# Late 70's TV movie - woman sacrifices herself for child (neanderthal?) with blanket

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I'm looking for the name of a late 70's/early 80's SFF tv movie or episode where a woman scientist sacrifices herself for a child (who may be neanderthal?) and they travel back in time or get beamed somewhere, never to return.

The memory is hazy (perhaps the neanderthal child is a chimp?) but a group of neanderthals or chimps have been beamed into a laboratory. At first this is a great achievement but the neanderthals or chimps do not adjust well. Eventually they must be sent back. In the meantime a woman scientist has formed a bond with a child subject. The woman has given the child a (blue?) blanket which the child finds soothing. It might not even be a blanket but some other calming token.

Just before the 'return' beaming (there might be a countdown) a crisis ensues where the child is freaking out, perhaps because it wants its blanket. The child touches the woman or the woman goes into the beaming room. In any case the step is irreversible and the woman and child get beamed or disintegrated together as the other scientists look on in despair.

Any help identifying this story would be most appreciated.

Comment: Duo of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56028/4804

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The story is ["The Ugly Little Boy" by Isaac Asimov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ugly_Little_Boy).   It was adapted into a [made for TV movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0176261/) in 1977.

[Youtube link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMJpj5YvyL8)