# Movie about a space station and an evil baby from a rock?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

It's from the late 60's or early 70's... It's a sci fi. All I remember is a space station with a bunch of people on it, one of the scientists was a woman. They were doing research of some kind on a rock... And they managed to beam an evil baby out of the rock. The scientists wanted to kill it... All except the woman scientist. She tried to save it and feed it... Damn thing had sharp teeth. In the end the baby was uncontrollable and the woman decided to beam her and the baby back into the rock... She went with the baby so it would have a mother  that's all I can remember.  Up to the challenge??

Comment: Welcome to scifi.stackexchange.com!  Please feel free have a look at the site tour and help center.  Your post is a good question that is definitely appropriate for this site.  Do try to keep your questions free of things like, "Up to the challenge??"  Trust me --- you'll find that most of us are constantly up to the challenge, without any extra prodding!!  :-)

Comment: Any chance you are misremembering the TVO Classics Dark and Dangerous episode "The Ugly Little Boy?" See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87173/4804 for some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "[The Ugly Little Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ugly_Little_Boy)" by Isaac Asimov.

It was made into a short made-for-TV film. At the end they...

> ...send the neanderthal child back home. The female scientist dives into the machine to be with him and they both get transported.

Comment: +1. A worthy suggestion, if I do say so myself.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod - It is indeed a worthy suggestion...although I'm a little perplexed as to why you weren't encouraged to posting your comment as an answer...

Comment: @user35594 - My guess is that he just didn't want the rep...

Comment: Yes. That's the one.Don't know why I remembered it being an alien....but I was only 5 when I watched it.